# "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions. An explicit expression ("@()") must be used. VS 22

Tags: html-helper, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022,
This code caused exception in the razor view:

```
object htmlAttr = null;
if (Model.ResourceInfo.Id > 0)
{
    htmlAttr = new {@class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled ="disabled"};
}
else
{
    htmlAttr = new { @class="form-control" };
}
```

[image: Exception in the view]

Answer (score 1):

Add "@" before @class worked for me

`htmlAttr = new {@@class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled ="disabled"};`

[image: No exception and worked in browser]

Browser : Vivaldi
IDE : VS22